# Error in loading json with os and pandas package

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I want to load a json and I run this source

```
b_path = '/home/r/Documents/TTx'
a = os.path.join(base_path, 'Tc.json')
b = json.load(open(a))['data']
```

but I have an error that I attach this error

then I add encoding(utf-8) to open for example

`b = json.load(open(a),encoding(utf-8))['data']`

but I have error still

How to solve my problem?

Comment: How working `b = pd.read_json(a)` ?

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much for your suggust but I have tested it and had same error but now I change path of dataset and could solve this problem.